# Number base conversion returning (-ve) value

Tags: java, base-conversion

I am self-learning Java programming and I was trying to do some number conversion from base 10 to any base, but I keep getting a negative value with the code below

```java
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberSystemConversion {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the  source base of the integer");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sBase = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the destination base of the integer");
        int dBase = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the integer");
        String s1 = sc.next();

        //int len = s1.length();
        int decNumber = 0;
        for (int i =0; i <= s1.length()-1;  i++) {
            decNumber += s1.indexOf(i)*Math.pow(sBase,i);
        }
        System.out.println(decNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your input for the scanner?

Comment: sBase =2, dBase=10, String s1=1111

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) method to get the index of a character. If it does not exist in the string, the `indexOf` returns a `-1`. That's how you get the negative values.

Consider `345` as the input. You are iterating (`i`) from `0` to `2` (`s.length() - 1` is 2).

***Hint:*** You can use instead this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
```

No need to deduct `1` from the length and check whether it is less or equal.

Then you check the `s1.indexOf(i)`. In the first iteration, `s1.indexOf(0)` is checked, and since there is no `0` in the string, it will return `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) method to get the index of a character. But it is totally unsuitable in your context. To iterate over the characters of a String, use [charAt()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) or even better [codePointAt()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)) like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)  {
    System.out.println( s.codePointAt(i) );
}
```

Once there, you will have to convert the character's unicode codepoint into the number you want to calculate with. This table may help:
https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf